# C# - Reading a specific float value from a process

Tags: c#, memory, extract

I'm currently working on a project where we measure a muscle's MEP-repsone with an electromyograph.

Long story short, the  company that made the machine we are using supplied us with software that doesn't have a convenient function too show the mean value of the MEP-amplitudes during the process.

I'm wondering how I would go about to read this specific value from the process (software) into a stand-alone program (so that I can have it on a separate screen to show the mean value). I thought about using memory reading in C#, but I have little experience with finding the right memory address that corresponds to the float value I'm trying to extract. Do you think that this would be the best solution, or is there some other method I could use to simplify the process? I'm mainly using C# because it's the language i know best.

Ps. I know how to write the stand-alone program, and memory reading in C#. I just don't know how to attack this problem the best way, considering my knowledge in debugging/reverse engineering is lacking at best.

Best regards,
Remmie

Comment: I haven't really written anything yet, and the software we're using is not opensource (unfortunately). However, the value of the EMG-response after a stimulation shows up in the program - the question is, how do I extract this value so that I can calculate the mean value for all the subsequent stimulations.

Comment: Feels a bit too broad for SO. If it is legitimate project - ask vendor for info... If just hacking around - there is no shortcut than actually learn about reverse engineering a bit and all memory layout details for different types data in native/managed code.

Comment: We did ask the vendor, with a rather disappointing "No such functions are or will be available in the near future" for an awnser. I guess i'll have to sit down and learn a bit about reverse engineering. It's mainly a time saver, so that the volunteers whom we preform these tests on don't have to sit around for 3 hours per session.